# Windows - hosts file resets without my interference

Tags: windows-7, windows, youtube, hosts

I have a pretty long list of time-wasting sites in the hosts file and it is working just fine, however I'm experiencing a very strange behavior - every day or *two* (my PC turns on automatically every day) from the file disappear two lines:

```
127.0.0.1 youtube.com
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
```

Even the line-breaking symbols stay there. I am using the latest stable Chrome and two Youtube-related extensions - [FancyTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkiabklhofojmagogdjdmhmbhngajopa) and [YouTube Ratings Preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgbhdenfmgbagncdmgbholejjpmmiank). I don't remove them because sometimes I need to visit YouTube and I don't want to deal with advertisement or rickrolls. The interesting part is that I tried to make the file read-only and to remove write-rights from everything except me, but it didn't help (flags haven't been reset). Is it one of the extensions or something else? Or maybe Flash?

Comment: YouTube has become self-aware.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving write permissions to "administrators" only, rather than yourself, and turn on UAC. As long as you run programs as a regular user, they should not have access to the file.

If a program asks for elevated permissions, check the file before accepting - it might give you a clue.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this later today.

Comment: Sorry for the... um.. delay. Recently gave it a try, no success. Over some time I've noticed, that Youtube isn't the only one, who disappears. A week before I've switched to the StayFocusd extension. It takes a bit less time to simply disable it than to find the hosts file and remove a line, but I've done that just once, the productivity seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Microsoft Security Essentials? [Sometimes](http://www.jmedved.com/2011/04/are-you-sure/) it detects a threat and changes file back to default.

Comment: Yes, but *only* the YouTube entries‽ `o.O`

Comment: No, I don't have any anti-virus products installed, and my file isn't being changed to default, just two lines, with _youtube_ in them.